# Eclipse SVN Version number available to embed in html?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I would like to automatically embed the SVN version of a any file within it's source so I can visually see where each file is from the web.

Comment: SVN supports [keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) but I've no idea how to do that from within Eclipse (or if it's possible).

Comment: http://blog.gorges.us/2009/03/how-to-enable-keywords-in-eclipse-and-subversion-svn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.keywords):

```
<!-- 
    SVN URL : $HeadURL$
    SVN Revision : $Revision$
-->
```

Comment: http://blog.gorges.us/2009/03/how-to-enable-keywords-in-eclipse-and-subversion-svn/